# My Y axis is inverted! How do I fix that?

Tags: call-of-duty-black-ops-2

When I play Black Ops 2, it seems that my xbox controller is inverted. Example: if I press up, my character looks down and vice versa. It was not like this before. Does anyone know how to reset the controller back to its original settings?

Answer (score 5):

Go to your Options and find "Look Inversion," then set it to "disabled."

Answer (score 1):

I think you set the controls to inverted, practically every shooter has this feature. Simply go to the options menu and turn it off there.